# ignoring empty values

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, empty

I have a function to convert comma seperated values out of a text field into the fitting currency format. It is working when the field is filled but it stops the whole "Mail calculation" when it´s empty, even when I don´t use the VAR in the current Mail. I have a lot of "not filled fields" and I want SF to ignore these fields. Anybody an idea?

My AMP:

```
set @P3_Product1_Price = lookup(@source,"P3_Product1_Price","countrylangkey",@countrylangkey)
set @P3_Product1_Price = Replace(@P3_Product1_Price,',','.')
set @P3_Product1_Pricedyn = Concat("%", "%=FormatCurrency('",@P3_Product1_Price,"','",@culturecode,"')=%", "%")
set @P3_Product1_Pricedyn = TreatAsContent(@P3_Product1_Pricedyn)
IF @culturecode == "de_CH" THEN SET @P3_Product1_Pricedyn = Replace(@P3_Product1_Pricedyn,'Fr.','CHF') ENDIF
```

The error message:
[image]

Comment: Can you let us know what you mean by 'stops'  Is there an error? If so, can you share it with us.

Comment: @Gortonington: sorry. See now attached above.

Comment: Thanks @Maik - I believe my answer below should help solve your issue. As it will skip those functions when the value is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing that it is giving you an error when the lookup comes back empty, I would go with the following code to skip the replace, formating, etc. on empty values.

I also included an ELSE statement in case you wanted to insert a default value for the price on those that do not have one in the lookup.

```
set @P3_Product1_Price = lookup(@source,"P3_Product1_Price","countrylangkey",@countrylangkey)

IF NOT EMPTY(@P3_Product1_Price) THEN

    set @P3_Product1_Price = Replace(@P3_Product1_Price,',','.')

    set @P3_Product1_Pricedyn = FormatCurrency(@P3_Product1_Price, @culturecode)

    IF @culturecode == "de_CH" THEN

        SET @P3_Product1_Pricedyn = Replace(@P3_Product1_Pricedyn,'Fr.','CHF') 

    ENDIF

ELSE

    SET @P3_Prodcut1_Pricedyn = 'Default Value Here'

ENDIF
```